# How do i add custom code from a user inside the <head> tag

Tags: javascript, html

i created a form builder, however, i need to find a way to have the person add their own tracking codes when they publish the forms, these tracking codes go in the  code.

```
<section class="tracking-codes">
    <h2> Please enter all tracking codes in here: </h2>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="code" placeholder="Facebook Pixel"> </input>
        <button type="button" onclick="codes()"> Add Code </button
    </form>
</section>
```

here is my js

```
function codes ()
{
    var trackingCode = document.getElementById('code');
    document.head.appendChild(trackingCode);
    console.log(trackingCode);
}
```

at this point, it does append the id of code but only the part of
    `<input type="text" id="code" placeholder="Facebook Pixel">`
and not the user input, how would i go about doing this? 
I have also tried the `.value` at the end of making the var of trackingcodes but it doesnt work.

Comment: You are adding an `input` element to the `head`? Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Along those lines, what is it you are wanting to add to the head?

Comment: A html input element is not supposed to be added the head section.

Comment: im just trying to allow users to add a tracking code in the head

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding html to the head section, you should use a hidden field input. Add it like this:

```
function codes ()
{
var trackingCode = document.getElementById('code').value;
var element = document.createElement('input');
element.type = 'hidden';
element.id = 'tracking';
document.head.appendChild(element);
console.log(trackingCode);
}
```

Comment: would i keep the html the same?

Comment: Yes, the page served from the server would be the same. This code simply adds a hidden input to the html, which will be posted to the server.